# Create multiple origins in one cloudfront distribution

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, cookies, amazon-cloudfront

I want to create cloudfront distribution with two origins. One origin which server S3 bucket static Website without using signed cookies or url. Second origin is also S3 Bucket where i have stored my images and i want access this bucket content using signed cookies. How should i do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where is your bottleneck.

Create two origins in CloudFront distribution and have the signed url setting in the behaviour for your created origin.

Hope it helps.